how to crop preview from one side in android camera2-api
i want to crop camera preview from top about 20 % of orignal height.
, my current code
                        // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                        // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                        // crop preview from top about 10% of the screen
                        Rect cropRect = new Rect(0, (int) (mPreviewSize.getHeight() * 0.1), mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, cropRect);
                        mState = STATE_STREAMING;
                        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);

but it is croping from all side not only from one side (yes it is cropping from top more but other side are also getting scaled)
